# scalasca cube linking error

Tags: makefile, zlib, cube

I'm trying to install cube library,required for installing SCALASCA.I've installed already PAPI,OPARI and Qt.I also installed zlib both from source and by apt-get.But during cube linking(make command) an error occurs refering to some classes of zlib.
This is the configuration command i use:
`./configure --prefix=/opt/cube-4.2.2 --with-qt=/opt/Qt --with-frontend-zlib=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu --with-compression=full`

this is the output from configuration: [cube lib configuration output](http://pastebin.com/XFbJ7wXe)

and this is the make output: [cube lib make command output](http://pastebin.com/rAeE8533)

The error:

```
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzofstream::gzofstream()'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzifstream::gzifstream(int, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzifstream::gzifstream()'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzfilebuf::~gzfilebuf()'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzifstream::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzofstream::close()'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzofstream::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
./.libs/libcube4.so: undefined reference to `gzifstream::close()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using xubuntu 14.04 on vmware

Comment: I had the same problem and it was gone when I installed zlib library and recompiled and reconfigured everything from scratch.